# Hermitian and Kähler Metrics for Projective Stiefel Manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Let $V(n,r)$ denote the complex Stiefel manifold of orthonormal complex
$r$-frames in complex $\mathbb{C}^n$-space. Each $V(n,r)$ admits a canonical $U(1)$-action, and the quotient with respect to this action is called a *projective Stiefel manifold*. In the case $r=1$, the Stiefel manifold reduces to the odd dimensional sphere, and the quotient reduces to complex projective $n$-space, which is a complex manifold, and moreover, a Kähler manifold.

By the work of [Wang](http://WANG,%20H.-C.:%20Closed%20%20manifolds%20%20with%20%20homogeneous%20%20complex%20%20structure%20,%20Amer.%20J.%20Math.%2076%20,%20(1954),%201%7B32), a projective projective Stiefel manifold admits a covariant complex structure if and only if it is even dimensional.

Do any of these complex manifolds admit an Hermitian or Kähler metric?